# Is the cut locus of a compact subset in an Alexandrov space negligible?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

Let $(M,d)$ be a compact, n dimensional Alexandrov space with curvature $\geqslant -1$ and without boundary. $\mathcal{H}^n$ is the n dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Let $K\subset M$ be a compact subset. 
Then for any $x \in M\backslash K$, there exists a foot point $z_x$ (not necessarily unique) such that $d(x,K)=d(x,z_x)$.

Is for $\mathcal{H}^n$-a.e. $x \in M \backslash K$, the geodesic connecting $z_x$ to $x$ is extendable? i.e. there exists some $y\neq x$ such that $d(z_x,y)=d(y,x)+d(x,z_x)$.

If the above is OK, what about general metric measure spaces (with Ricci curvature bounded below)?